# Can I add an IF condition in between query builders of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

I don't know what they are exactly called but I call the query builders 
`$this->db->select()`.

Is it possible to do this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('table_name')
         if(1)
         {
          ->where('column_name',1)
         }
         ->order_by('column_name','ASC');
```

If not are there any alternatives I can do?

Note: I just want to make my code short and not create another function where the only difference is that there is a `where()` in the function.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you need to do, nor what you've tried and are not able to sort out. There's a lot of code and explanation missing here in order to allow some understanding of what you intend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table_name');
if(1)
{
    $this->db->where('column_name',1);
}
$this->db->order_by('column_name','ASC');
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I can't separate them.

Comment: while your answer is correct, maybe you would want to explain a bit more about the difference of what is happening, if you use the semicolon `;` or not. That would make the answer useful for later visitors as well!

Comment: @blur, You can put Query Builder calls in any order with the exception of `get()` or `get_where()` which need to be last because they actually execute the query statement.